# C Programming strcat.asm not found error debugging

Tags: c, debugging

I am working on a homework assignment and have been attempting to debug my program, but to no avail. I am trying to read in an input file then add each char to the end of a linked list, but my program keeps crashing and says strcat.asm not found, as well as "Unhandled exception at 0x0FA74127 (msvcr120d.dll) in... writing location 0x00000000000000" which from looking at other questions on here appears to be a problem with a NULL pointer. After 3 hours of dealing with this single problem I am turning to you all for help, thank you.
This is the full code:

```
    #include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


#define LENGTH 80

struct boggleDataNode {
    char data[3];
    struct boggleDataNode *nextData;
};

void readData(struct boggleDataNode **);
struct boggleDataNode* makeNode(char *);
void display(struct boggleDataNode *);

int main() {
    struct boggleDataNode * head = NULL;
    readData(&head);
    display(head);
}

void readData(struct boggleDataNode **headRef){
    //initializing variables including
    //opening the input file
    char dataLine[LENGTH];
    char *data;
    char *fileName = "BoggleData.txt";

    FILE *filePointer;

    printf("Trying to open file %s\n", fileName);
    filePointer = fopen(fileName, "r"); //read mode
    printf("Successfully opened file %s\n", fileName);

    if (filePointer == NULL){
        perror("Error while opening file. \n");
        exit(0);
    }

    //loop until find end of file
    while (fgets(dataLine, LENGTH, filePointer) != NULL){
        for (char *tok = strtok(dataLine, " "); tok; tok = strtok(NULL, " "))
        {
            data = tok;
            printf("data = %s\n", tok);
            if (*headRef == NULL){
                *headRef = makeNode(data);
                head = *headRef;
            }
            else{
                head->nextData = makeNode(data);
                head = head->nextData;
            }
        }
    }

    fclose(filePointer);

}//close readData

struct boggleDataNode* makeNode(char *data){
    struct boggleDataNode* temp = (struct boggleDataNode*) malloc(sizeof(struct boggleDataNode));
    strcpy(temp->data, data);
    temp->nextData = NULL;
    return temp;

    /*
    //allocate node
    struct boggleDataNode* temp = (struct boggleDataNode*) malloc(sizeof(struct boggleDataNode));
    struct boggleDataNode* right = (struct boggleDataNode*) malloc(sizeof(struct boggleDataNode));

    if ((*headRef) == NULL){
    strcpy((*headRef)->data, data);
    (*headRef)->nextData = NULL;
    }
    else{
    strcpy(temp->data, data);
    temp->nextData = NULL;

    // ======== The program appears to break here ================
    right = (*headRef);
    while (right->nextData != NULL)
    right = right->nextData;

    right->nextData = temp;
    right = temp;
    right->nextData = NULL;
    }
    }  */
}

void display(struct boggleDataNode *headRef){

    struct boggleDataNode *helper = headRef;

    if (helper == NULL){
        return;
    }
    else{
        printf("============================================\n");
        printf("Node #        Data\n");
        printf("============================================\n");

        int counter = 1;

        while (helper != NULL){
            printf("%5d \t %2s\n", counter++, helper->data);
            helper = helper->nextData;
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

This is the input file

```
D R L X E I
C P O H S A
N H N L Z R
W T O O T A
I O S S E T 
N W E G H E
B O O J A B
U I E N E S
P S A F K F
I U N H M Qu
Y R D V E L
V E H W H R
I O T M U C
T Y E L T R
S T I T Y D
A G A E E N
```

Comment: I suspect that you are getting compiler warnings about argument types and ignoring them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try a bit more object-oriented approach in C.

1. Change the body of your main to be:

   ```
   struct boggleDataNode * head = NULL;
   readData(&head);
   display(head);
   ```

   `NULL` does a good job of signifying an empty linked list.
2. Correct the beginning of the `readData` definition to (note two asterisks):

   ```
   void readData(struct boggleDataNode **headRef){
   ```

   This needs to match the prototype you declared earlier in the program.
3. Replace the declaration/prototype for `addEntry` to

   ```
   struct boggleDataNode* makeNode(char *);
   ```
4. And replace the definition of `addEntry` with

   ```
   struct boggleDataNode* makeNode(char *data){
       struct boggleDataNode* temp =
           (struct boggleDataNode*) malloc(sizeof(struct boggleDataNode));
       strcpy(temp->data, data);
       temp->nextData = NULL;
       return temp;
   }
   ```

   Note that this method is much easier to reason about. It will allocate memory, copy the string data, and leave the link to the next node indicating that it isn't pointing to anything. This is basically the job of a constructor in post-C languages. Note, you allocate memory here, but you need to `free` this memory later.
5. And finally, replace the `addEntry` call in the `readData` method to:

   ```
   if (*headRef == NULL) {
       *headRef = makeNode(data);
       head = *headRef;
   } else {
       head->nextData = makeNode(data);
       head = head->nextData;
   }
   ```

   In addition, you will need to declare `struct boggleDataNode * head = NULL;` in the `readData` method.

Comment: I appreciate the help, but unfortunately it is still breaking at the same point in visual studio.

Comment: But also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5797548/c-linked-list-inserting-node-at-the-end

Comment: This is a C program, and `<cstring>` is what C++ calls C's `<string.h>`.   The C preprocessor probably won't like that.

Comment: @DustinSchmidt updated the answer, do you still get errors? If so what do you see?

Comment: @PrashantKumar, sorry about the delay but I had to work all day, I am trying to implement your suggestions but it seems I am missing a head declaration in readData.

Answer (score 0):

See my notes in the code.  For a linked list you sure do have a lot of code, particularly in you addNode function.

```
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>

    #define LENGTH 80

    struct boggleDataNode {
        char data[3];
        struct boggleDataNode *nextData;
    };

    struct boggleDieSideNode {
        char dieSideData[3];
        struct boggleDieSideNode *nextSide;
    };

    void readData(struct boggleDataNode **);
    void addEntry(struct boggleDataNode **, char *);
    void display(struct boggleDataNode *);

    int main() {

        int counter = 0;

        struct boggleDataNode * head = (struct boggleDataNode*) malloc(sizeof(struct boggleDataNode));
```

Here you assign `head` to point at some memory, but you never initialize that memory.
I'm also puzzled since from my understanding `head` should be an empty list at this point in the program since you haven't read anything in yet, so unless this is supposed to be some sort of terminal node, empty linked lists are usually just null pointers.

```
        struct boggleDieSideNode *head1 = NULL;
        readData(&head);
```

You are passing `readData` and argument of type `struct boggleDataNode **` which makes sense if you want readData to be able to change what `head` points to, which I think that you do, but...

```
        display(head);

        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }

    void readData(struct boggleDataNode *headRef){
```

... `readData` expects an argument of type `struct boggleDataNode *`, so you've passed in the wrong type (but the right value, meaning that I think that you have passed in a WORD with the correct value).

```
        //initializing variables including
        //opening the input file
        int counter = 96;
        int i = 0;
        char dataLine[LENGTH];
        char *data;
        char *fileName = "BoggleData.txt";

        FILE *filePointer;

        printf("Trying to open file %s\n", fileName);
        filePointer = fopen(fileName, "r"); //read mode
        printf("Successfully opened file %s\n", fileName);

        if (filePointer == NULL){
            perror("Error while opening file. \n");
            exit(0);
        }

        //loop until find end of file
        while ( fgets(dataLine, LENGTH, filePointer) != NULL){
            for (char *tok = strtok(dataLine, " "); tok; tok = strtok(NULL, " "))
            {
                data = tok;
                printf("data = %s\n", tok);
                addEntry(headRef, data);
```

You pass `addEntry` a `struct boggleDataNode *` here, but ...

```
            }
        }

        fclose(filePointer);

    }//close readData

    void addEntry(struct boggleDataNode **headRef, char *data){
```

... `addEntry` expected a `struct boggleDataNode **`.

```
        //allocate node
        struct boggleDataNode* temp = (struct boggleDataNode*) malloc(sizeof(struct boggleDataNode));
        struct boggleDataNode* right = (struct boggleDataNode*) malloc(sizeof(struct boggleDataNode));

        if ((*headRef) == NULL){
```

If this condition is ever true...

```
            strcpy((*headRef)->data, data);
            (*headRef)->nextData = NULL;
```

These two lines of code are errors because they are dereferencing a NULL pointer.

```
        }else{
            strcpy(temp->data, data);
            temp->nextData = NULL;

// ======== The program appears to break here ================
            right = (*headRef);
```

You had allocated some memory and assigned that to `right` earlier, and now you've assigned a new value to `right`, which means that you've lost the only pointer to the memory that you allocated earlier.  This is a memory leak, but it's almost certainly not what's crashing your program.

```
            while (right->nextData != NULL)
                right = right->nextData;
```

I don't know what you're trying to do here, but this code scares me a lot.

```
            right->nextData = temp;
            right = temp;
            right->nextData = NULL;
        }
    }

void display(struct boggleDataNode *headRef){

    struct boggleDataNode *helper = headRef;

    if (helper == NULL){
        return;
    }
    else{
        printf("============================================\n");
        printf("Node #        Data\n");
        printf("============================================\n");

        int counter = 1;

        while (helper != NULL){
            printf("%5d \t %2s\n", counter++, helper->data);
            helper = helper->nextData;
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: thanks for the break down, that actually is helping me quite a bit, unfortunately I have to agree with your assessment my code scares me too. It's going to be a long day tomorrow. I'll make the edits tomorrow. Thanks again