# EXC_BAD ACCESS when adding node to linked list in C

Tags: c, linked-list, exc-bad-access

I am trying to implement a function to add a new node at the end of a linked list, found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5797548/). However, when running the code below in Xcode, I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error at the if statement marked with the comment //ERROR

This is my first serious encounter with linked lists, could anyone explain what I am doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct _node {
    int value;
    struct _node *next;
} node;

int addNodeBottom(int val, node *head);

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    node *head;
    head = NULL;

    for (int i = 1; i<11; i++) {
        addNodeBottom(i, head);
    }


    node *temp = head;
    while (head != NULL) {
        head = temp->next;
        free(temp);
        temp = head;
    }

    return 0;
}

int addNodeBottom(int val, node *head){

    //create new node
    node *newNode = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));

    if(newNode == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to allocate memory for new node\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    newNode->value = val;
    newNode->next = NULL;

    //check for first insertion
    if(head->next == NULL){                //ERROR
        head->next = newNode;
        printf("added at beginning\n");
    }

    else {
        //else loop through the list and find the last
        //node, insert next to it
        node *current = head;
        while (current->next != NULL) {
            current = current->next;
        }
        current->next = newNode;
        printf("added later\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If the first node is `NULL`,  `addNodeBottom` can not be used. It is because assume that node already exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
head = NULL;
...
if(head->next == NULL)
```

Because of this. You should initialize head as a valid pointer first. The possible solution to your problem is passing `node** head` to function instead of `node* headPtr` and check `*headPtr == NULL` to make it possible to work with `head = NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you dereference a pointer to `NULL`. See here in `main` —

```
head = NULL;
```

But then in function, you dereference it —

```
if(head->next == NULL){                //ERROR
```

without checking if `head` is `NULL` or not . Handle the situation when `head` is `NULL` and then proceed if it is not `NULL`.