# add() method for a linked list

Tags: java, methods, linked-list, addition, nodes

I'm trying to create a method that will add a node to a linked list but so far have been unsuccessful. Here's my code with my member vars:

```
private Object data; 
private int size = 0;
private Node head = null; 
private Node tail = null;

    public void add(Object item){
    Node temp = head;
    if (head != null) {
        // THIS IS THE PROBLEM SITE

        while(temp.getNext()!=null){
            temp=temp.getNext();
        }
        //set next value equal to item
        Node ab = (Node) item; // It says this is an invalid cast. How do I get around this??
        ab.setNext(ab);

    } 
    else{
        head = new Node(item);
    }
    size++;
}
```

Also here's my Node class for reference:

```
public class Node {

// Member variables.
private Object data; // May be any type you'd like.
private Node next;

public Node(Object obj) {
    this.data = obj; // Record my data!
    this.next = null; // Set next neighbour to be null.
}
// Sets the next neighbouring node equal to nextNode
public void setNext(Node nextNode){
    this.next=nextNode;
}
// Sets the item equal to the parameter specified.
public void setItem(Object newItem){
    this.data = newItem;
}
// Returns a reference to the next node.
public Node getNext(){
    return this.next;
}
// Returns this node ís item.
public Object getItem() {
    return this.data;   
}
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Can you explain what 'unsuccessful' means. Are you getting an error?

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5797548/c-linked-list-inserting-node-at-the-end

Comment: In the future, you should add the exception(s) you get so that it's easier to isolate/understand the problem for the others.

Answer (score 7):

you don't want to cast your `item` as a node, you want to create a new node and set the `data` in it to be the `item`

replace this :

```
Node ab = (Node) item; // It says this is an invalid cast. How do I get around this??
ab.setNext(ab);
```

by something like this :

```
Node newNode  = new Node();
newNode.setData(item);
temp.setNext(newNode);
```